# Templating in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a problem creating a "sub"-template in **asp.net core**.
The idea is to define a complete html-bootstrap-block in a template file and call it in another parent/master cshtml file.

ViewModel Person (filled in the controller)

```
namespace RazorTemplating.Models.HomeViewModels
{
    public class Person
    {
        [Required]
        [MinLength(2)]
        public string Firstname { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MinLength(2)]
        public string Lastname { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(3)]
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public Group MainGroup { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The master view called by the controller (Index.cshtml)

**Edit**: The *input-template*-tags reference a custom tag helper.

```
@model RazorTemplating.Models.HomeViewModels.Person

<div class="row">
    <input-template for="Firstname" />
</div>
<div class="row">
    <input-template for="Lastname" />
</div>
<div class="row">
    <input-template for="Age" />
</div>
<div class="row">
    <input-template for="MainGroup" />
</div>
```

Inputbox Bootstrap template file (InputBootstrapTemplate.cshtml)

```
@model dynamic

<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="@Model" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="@Model" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="@Model" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

How i can fill the dynamic model for template file, from the *input-template*-tag helper?

Edit: Something is changing in advance for templating in ASP.NET Core https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/788

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you want to render something like custom controls. For example, render control with some wrapping html, label, input by one line. Right? In this case [tag helpers](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro.html) fit your need very good.

Also you could take a look at new feature - [view components](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/view-components.html). It is like small (one action) controller + view pair. It is good to render blocks, like news, last added comments etc.

Feel free to ask for details.

Comment: I know, the *<input-template/>* tag is from a custom tag helper. The problem is: How can i pass the ViewModel and Property to the dynamic model in InputBoostrapTemplate.cshtml?

Comment: Don't know :( I'm using tag helpers only generating html from code: https://github.com/Platformus/Platformus/tree/master/src/Platformus.Barebone.Backend/Areas/Backend/Code/TagHelpers