# Custom Model attribute for outputting html data- attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to be able to create an attribute e.g. [AttachDatePicker] to decorate my ViewModel datetime properties so when I use scaffolding it outputs e.g. data-datepicker as an html attribute for the html element I want the datepicker attached to.

I could do it based on the microsoft example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation#iclientmodelvalidator) but it doesn't feel right as it is not related to validation what i need.

Ideally i would like to avoid creating custom templates. Any ideas?

Comment: I think it's better if you look into templating: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674824/templating-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score 0):

Why not define an [Editor Template](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-display-and-editor-templates/) and attribute the DateTime property with `[UIHint]`?

For example, create Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Datepicker.cshtml

```
@model DateTime

@{
   IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>(); 
   // TODO: retrieve annotations from Model Metadata and add html attributes accordingly, e.g. "required"
   htmlAttributes.Add("data-datepicker", "");
}

<div class="@* TODO: set classes depending on your CSS framework *@">
    @Html.TextBox("", Model, htmlAttributes)
</div>
```

Attribute your ViewModels using `[UIHint("{name of editor template}")]`

```
[Required] // example of an annotation you might want to handle
[UIHint("Datepicker")]
public DateTime SelectedDate { get; set; }
```

Render the property with `EditorFor`, this will dispatch to the correct template

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SelectedDate)
```